# Angular js Remove query parameters when changing the url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, route-provider

I am facing issue in angular js, right now we have two urls in our application,
http://localhost/xyz?page=documents&view=grid&sortorder=desc&sortby=updatedate&limit=35&offset=0

and then we another url
http://localhost/abc

When i move from the first url to the second url it carries the query params from the first url, this is how the second url looks like
http://localhost/abc?page=documents&view=grid&sortorder=desc&sortby=updatedate&limit=35&offset=35

We don't the fetch url carrying the query params from the first page. I am new to angular js, I have came across few options like 
 $location.search({});
$location.url($location.path())

But those didn't work at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "moving from the first URL to the second URL"?

Comment: :) Changing from one page to another page

Answer (score 0):

I think i know what you mean, to remove parameters use

`$location.url($location.path());`

Hope it helps

Comment: We are using routeprovider in our application, where do I keep this line to have the result?

Comment: I have tried using your solution in routechangestart but that didn't work, can you let me know how to use your solution

Answer (score 0):

Check this [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) for the location with angular

Answer (score 0):

1.Save the query object `$location.search()`in some place (local storage or cookies), then in the target controller  `$.map(query,funcion(k,v){ $location.search(k,v});`

2.Dynamically append to the end url2 + `$location.path()` in href attribute

Answer (score 0):

`$location.url` changes path, search and hash.
So, `$location.url('new_path')` should work!